# Koush ION crashes after Gradle upgrade

Tags: android, ion-koush

After Gradle upgrade ION gives me this error, when trying to send very simple request.
It gives me same error on AVD and my physical device. For now I dodged error with going reverting the upgrade.
What could be causing following error?

```
2020-10-24 12:34:14.275 20605-20647/my.example.project E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: ion-ion
Process: my.example.project, PID: 20605
java.lang.AssertionError
    at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.write(AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.java:474)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.handleHandshakeStatus(AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.java:378)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.handshake(AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.java:182)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncSSLSocketMiddleware.tryHandshake(AsyncSSLSocketMiddleware.java:89)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncSSLSocketMiddleware$2.onConnectCompleted(AsyncSSLSocketMiddleware.java:106)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncSocketMiddleware.lambda$getSocket$3$AsyncSocketMiddleware(AsyncSocketMiddleware.java:217)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.http.-$$Lambda$AsyncSocketMiddleware$glazjOxu-iNIRY4N890Wl1ngyGo.onCompleted(Unknown Source:12)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.lambda$setCallback$0(SimpleFuture.java:216)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.-$$Lambda$SimpleFuture$h_gK5Y1XHZI1H8JTE2xOg4dXbp8.onCompleted(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture$FutureCallsite.loop(SimpleFuture.java:130)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.handleCallbackUnlocked(SimpleFuture.java:153)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java:195)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java:175)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.-$$Lambda$VNAuWcttAhMr3VsWCERbmWE6yR0.success(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.lambda$success$4(SimpleFuture.java:287)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.-$$Lambda$SimpleFuture$DxIsaj7NQi76eWgOKS4iviWPLV0.onCompleted(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture$FutureCallsite.loop(SimpleFuture.java:130)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.handleCallbackUnlocked(SimpleFuture.java:153)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java:195)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java:182)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.http.-$$Lambda$cBC5du-82c5EcL72rP5wNK7Y2Y4.onConnectCompleted(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.runLoop(AsyncServer.java:906)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.run(AsyncServer.java:727)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.access$800(AsyncServer.java:46)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer$8.run(AsyncServer.java:681)
```

I can't find same error in issues list of this library.

Answer (score 9):

I am a bit late to answer, but if someone is still looking for a solution , simply update the Ion version to **3.1.0** in *app.gradle* file and it should fix the crash.

```
implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:3.1.0'
```

Answer (score 5):

Did you try this: https://github.com/koush/ion/issues/937 ?

```
Solution 1:
Go to: File > Invalidate Caches/Restart and select Invalidate and Restart

Solution 2:
Go to: Build > Select Build Variant and select release instead of debug
```

Comment: it's fixed on version 3.1.0 ,check in the link koush comment